# Build a general tree with C (use a linkedlist to hold the children)

Tags: c, types, tree, declaration, definition

Try to build a tree in C. The children has to be contained in a linkedlist. But when I use "struct listNode*" in the definition of struct treeNode, listNode is not declared yet. So is there any way to declare this first? Or anyway to get around this? Thanks!

```
/*** Build a tree ***/
typedef struct treeNode {
    char* target;
    char* commands;
    struct listNode* children;
} tNode;

/*** Build a linkedlist ***/
typedef struct listNode {
    struct treeNode dependency;
    struct listNode* next;
} lNode;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use what's called forward declaration. So your code should look like this

```
/*** Build a tree ***/
struct listNode;

typedef struct treeNode {
    char* target;
    char* commands;
    struct listNode* children;
} tNode;

/*** Build a linkedlist ***/
typedef struct listNode {
    struct treeNode dependency;
    struct listNode* next;
} lNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the following to your snippet

```
struct listNode;
```

This is called a forward declaration.

The struct is not defined at this point, but the name is known, which is sufficient as you only want to reference it (with a pointer), not include it (which would require knowledge of its size).

Note that the restriction that you can only use pointers on yet-to-be-defined types actually makes sense: It makes

```
struct A {
    struct B b;
    int a;
};

struct B {
    struct A a;  /* Uh, what's that? struct B contains struct A
                  * which contains struct B... Now what's the size
                  * of either of these structs? */
};
```

an invalid construct (because it prevents circular dependencies).